# How to suppress QXcbConnection: XCB error

Tags: kde, qt, kde-plasma-5

I'm using KDE Plasma under Arch Linux and there are a lot of logs such as

```
kwin_x11[5129]: qt.qpa.xcb: QXcbConnection: XCB error: 3 (BadWindow), sequence: 11416, resource id: 56623191, major code: 20 (GetProperty), minor code: 0
```

in my journal.

These errors turned out to be harmless and I'd like to suppress them so that my journal doesn't get flooded. A popular solution I found was to set `QT_LOGGING_RULES="*=false"` but this disables logging completely even where it's actually useful.

I wonder how I can target only this Qt logging category and leave others untouched?

I've tried e.g. `QT_LOGGING_RULES="qt.qpa.xcb.*=false"` `QT_LOGGING_RULES="qpa.xcb.*=false"` `QT_LOGGING_RULES="qt.*.xcb.*=false"` etc but none of them worked.

Comment: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-56893

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far the best I could do:

```sh
export QT_LOGGING_RULES='*.debug=false;qt.qpa.*=false'
```

Comment: Or in your main() try   qputenv("QT_LOGGING_RULES","*.debug=false;qt.qpa.*=false"); // supress anoying messages

Comment: `qt.core.logging: Ignoring malformed logging rule: ''*.debug=false;qt.qpa.*=false''`

I'm getting this on Ubuntu 16.04 and the same `QXcbConnection` error keeps printing.

Comment: Advice on ArchLinux wiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Qt#Disable/Change_Qt_journal_logging_behaviour

Answer (score -1):

As someone has pointed out in the previous answer, for some reason the syntax for specifying multiple rules via `QT_LOGGING_RULES` involving `;` doesn't work on Ubuntu.

What worked for me was using `QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules` and using `\n` as separator for the individual rules for this to work. Extending on the previous answer: `export QLoggingCategory::setFilterRules(QStringLiteral("*.debug=false\nqt.qpa.*=false"))`

Comment: Sorry, a semicolon as rule delimiter is appropriate. See the [QT Documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qloggingcategory.html): *"Logging rules can also be specified in a QT_LOGGING_RULES environment variable; multiple rules can also be separated by semicolons"*.

Comment: Corrected the answer. `Qt_LOGGING_RULES` for some reason doesn't work with the `;` on Ubuntu, but it also doesn't work with `\n`. Problem fixed by using `QLoggingCategory`.